# What is the OS X equivalent of "useradd -r -d /opt/otrs/ -c 'OTRS user' otrs" and "usermod -G nogroup otrs www-data"

Tags: linux, macos, bash, permissions, otrs

I am trying to install **otrs** on a mac. I am wondering what is the **OS X** equivalent of the following commands?

```
useradd -r -d /opt/otrs/ -c 'OTRS user' otrs
usermod -G nogroup otrs www-data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link might be helpful: http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_creating_new_users

And this script gives further information and examples: http://wiki.freegeek.org/index.php/Mac_OSX_adduser_script

According to that, the following commands should do it:

```
dscl . create /Users/otrs
dscl . create /Users/otrs RealName "OTRS user"
dscl . create /Users/otrs NFSHomeDirectory /opt/otrs
dseditgroup -o edit -t user -a otrs nogroup
dseditgroup -o edit -t user -a otrs otrs
dseditgroup -o edit -t user -a otrs www-data
```

Comment: You also need to set `UniqueID` to something unique (for a system user, this should be less than 500), and `PrimaryGroupID` to -1 (nogroup).